# GWT Dynamic String Internationalization showcase

Tags: dynamic, gwt, internationalization

have anyone tried to switch from Static String Internationalization to dynamic one? I want to reduce number of permutations to one per browser but cannot find any tutorial how to implement Dynamic String Internationalization in Java. Official docs covers tutorial only for static implementation. Seeing proper example of implementation of this approach would be really helpful.

I want to reduce number of permutations to one per browser by implementing Dynamic String Internationalization in Java.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you are referring to at https://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization in turn links to the javadoc for `Dictionary`, which can be found at https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html.

On that page, there are two code snippets that demonstrate the idea.

First, the host page (or some other JS that runs on the host page) should provide an object with keys and values that represent the data you want to access at runtime. In this example, they load theme data, rather than strings for messages:

```js
var CurrentTheme = {
  highlightColor: "#FFFFFF",
  shadowColor: "#808080",
  errorColor: "#FF0000",
  errorIconSrc: "stopsign.gif"
};
```

This could also be assigned as something like `window.CurrentTheme = {...` instead, so long as it is attached to the global window scope in the host window.

Next, a `Dictionary` instance can be created and given the same name as the object was assigned to. That dictionary can then be queries for the various keys - note that the keys can even change at runtime - there's neither a requirement that the keys nor the values are constants.

```java
  Dictionary theme = Dictionary.getDictionary("CurrentTheme");

  String highlightColor = theme.get("highlightColor");
  String shadowColor = theme.get("shadowColor");
  applyShadowStyle(highlightColor, shadowColor);

  String errorColor = theme.get("errorColor");
  String errorIconSrc = theme.get("errorIconSrc");
  Image errorImg = new Image(errorIconSrc);
  showError(errorColor, errorImg);
```